# Calculating the percentage of a Party List of Members to rounded numbers (Because members cannot be fractions)

Tags: math, percentage, selection-sort

If I had a list in a party, say 10 people, and I needed to find 25% of that list of people, you could say the answer is 2.5 people.

However, if I had a list of 1 person (go with it), and I needed to find 25% of that list of people, I cannot say the answer is 25% of a person.

Because we exist (as wholes)

So to make this practical. Let's say I want to determine how many seats Party A versus B receives in an election.

Let's say the total number of seats available are 4.There are also 4 voters with only 1 vote each.

We have Party A, which as 3 votes and Party B has 1 vote.
If Party A has over 3 candidates, let's say 4 candidates - the top 3 candidates will be selected.

Since Party B only 1 vote they can only be allocated 1 seat.
So, this means, they will get the last remaining vote.

I would sum this up with this formula:

NumberOfSeatsAllocatedtoParty = (CountofVotes/TotalNumberofVoters) * NumberofSeatsToFill

```
(For Party A) 
x = 3/4 * 4 
x = 3

(For Party B)
x = 1/4 *4
x=1
```

Makes sense right?

Ok, however, let's assume there are only 2 positions to fill (not 4)
Again here is the formula

NumberOfSeatsAllocatedtoParty = (CountofVotes/TotalNumberofVoters) * NumberofSeatsToFill

```
(For Party A) 
x = 3/4 * 2 
x = 1

(For Party B)
x = 1/4 * 2
x = .5
```

Therein lies the problem, I cannot allocate half a person.  Sure I can round up in this example, but should we always? What if x = .2 for example.

My gut instinct is to always have minimum members in a party, but I would like the flexibility just in case.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: As you asked for pointers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_%28politics%29 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_apportionment might be relevant for turning percentages into integral number of representatives. They both list and compare different methods, so following these links will give you more details on each.

Comment: Python's [pywaffle](https://pypi.org/project/pywaffle/) package implements such an algorithm.  You might want to look into its source code.  Note that a perfect rule doesn't exist, each approach has its drawbacks.

Comment: What I ended up using is the Dhoudt method (knowing each election could be different).